# jest.config.ts: "registerer.enabled is not a function" error when running jest from Github Actions

Tags: node.js, jestjs, github-actions, tsconfig, ts-jest

When running jest locally, it instantiates my app and runs tests without any issues.

When running jest inside github actions, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file /home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/jest.config.ts

TypeError: registerer.enabled is not a function
    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:118:13)
```

the `package.json` script entry is just:`"test": "jest"`

and the `jest.config.ts` file is:

```
import tsJestUtils from 'ts-jest/utils'
import tsConf from './tsconfig.json'

const rootDir = __dirname
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = tsJestUtils
const {
  compilerOptions: { paths },
} = tsConf

const config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: [`${rootDir}/src`],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(paths, {
    prefix: `${rootDir}/src`,
  }),
}

export default config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So I just bypassed use of typescript for my jest config entirely**, and went with an equivalent `jest.config.js` file based on [the docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options). Works in Github Actions now, runner does not fail! \o/

---

I am still not sure what the issue was, but I think `ts-node` just wasn't processing the config file properly. I feel like the actual failure was with the attempt to load a *.ts* config file, specifically [at this point in the source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/7109b8ccea2e0f70b6ad8eae02cd36b6c2841604/packages/jest-config/src/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.ts#L83) when it tries to call `registerer.enabled()`.

Comment: Since I didn't have access to upgrading ts-node, this approach also fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by upgrading to `"ts-node": "^8.5.0"`